# How to define normal-mode keychords in evil mode

Tags: key-bindings, evil

A vim user trying to make the leap to emacs here. A roadblock I'm facing right now is a small convenience-remapping. These remaps aren't important, but my difficulty in making them makes me worry I'm fundamentally misunderstanding something.

The maps as I have them now:

```
(evil-define-key 'normal evil-normal-state-map (kbd "<key-chord> C-w C-k") 'evil-window-up)
(evil-define-key 'normal evil-normal-state-map (kbd "<key-chord> C-w C-j") 'evil-window-down)
```

These are meant to make the usual vim window motion commands (C-w k, C-w j, etc.) a bit more forgiving on my often rather stupid fingers. Am I missing something fundamental, still, about this? Do I need to create my own minor mode / separate keymapping just for this tiny addition?

The symptom: Even with these mappings in my `.emacs`, I still can't switch between windows with C-w C-k and C-w C-j keychords. The minibuffer helpfully reports that those chords are unbound.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update: `evil-define-key` is for a different purpose, namely installing a keybinding for a specific Evil state involving a mode's map.  For example you could configure `emacs-lisp-mode` to do something different with `RET` in `insert` state.  As you're not making use of this, `define-key` with `eval-after-load` or `with-eval-after-load` is the more sensible option for customizing Evil.

Please study `evil-maps.el` (which you can look up from inside Emacs with `M-x find-library`) to know what keymaps to modify.  Given this information, the correct invocations are:

```
(define-key evil-window-map (kbd "C-k") 'evil-window-up)
(define-key evil-window-map (kbd "C-j") 'evil-window-down)
```

Or if you want to do it properly, defer these forms until Evil is enabled:

```
(with-eval-after-load 'evil-maps
  (define-key evil-window-map (kbd "C-k") 'evil-window-up)
  (define-key evil-window-map (kbd "C-j") 'evil-window-down))
```

On older Emacs versions than 24.4:

```
(eval-after-load 'evil-maps
  '(progn
    (define-key evil-window-map (kbd "C-k") 'evil-window-up)
    (define-key evil-window-map (kbd "C-j") 'evil-window-down)))
```

Comment: Thank you for the fishing lesson! I've been working my way through some manuals but hadn't run across the `find-library` function yet.

Is there a reason you use `define-key` directly, rather than using evil's `evil-define-key`?

Comment: Hmm well since there are no examples of using `evil-define-key` for specifically the `evil-window-map` keys in the source you've pointed me to, I suppose that suffices to explain why you use the more general `define` function.

Comment: Yes, `evil-define-key` is limited to state-related maps.  Otherwise it desugars to `define-key` with `eval-after-load' and multiple keybindings in an invocation, so whether you use it for these is personal preference.

Comment: After reading [this bug report](https://bitbucket.org/lyro/evil/issues/301/evil-define-key-for-minor-mode-does-not) I've realized what the purpose of `evil-define-key` actually is and edited my answer appropriately.